# Difference between .space and .word directives

Tags: assembly, arm

I am just starting to learn assembly code for ARM-family processors in class. I know that the .word directive declares a variable of one word size and that the .space directory skips over a certain number of bytes. So my question is, how would the following two differ? (Assuming a word size of 32 bits)

```
foo: .word 0
```

vs.

```
bar: .space 4
```

Also, (a somewhat tangential question but) is there any way to declare uninitialized variables in assembly? It seems to me you always have to assign an initial value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: uninitialized if possible would be specific to the assembler/toolchain.  You can allocate memory in the linker script and access the address to that memory in assembly language without having to use .space nor .arm.  You can also simply supply the address in the assembly language and not need to use a label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.space means** that advances the location counter by the number of bytes specified by the value of expression. The assembler fills the space with zeros.

**.word means**
Truncates the values of the expressions specified in the comma-separated list to 16-bit values, and assembles the values in successive locations. The values of the expressions must be absolute.

The operands for the .word directive can optionally have the following form:
The expressionVal is a 16-bit value. 
The optional expressionRep is a non-negative expression that specifies how many times to replicate the value of expressionVal. 
The expression value (expressionVal) and repetition count (expressionRep) must be absolute.

The .word directive automatically aligns its data and preceding labels on a word boundary. You can disable this feature with the .align 0 directive.

Comment: A word is 32 bits for ARM not 16.  But, assembly language is specific to the assembler, the tool, not the target.  In general .word allocates words based on the that assemblers definition of a word for that target.  So far I have not seen .word for arm be 16 bits.